# Flower Power: What Kind?

Tags: riddle, word

What kind of flower is made of

1. a vehicle

and

2. a synonym for country

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That would be a

> Carnation (a **car** is a vehicle, and **nation** is a synonym for country)

Comment: +1, beat me by 18 seconds although it took a few tries to get past the minimum character restriction.

Comment: I upvoted your answer as well. I know how annoying it is to get beaten to the punch, it's happened to me more than enough times.

Comment: Both answers are correct

Answer (score 14):

Answer:

> Carnation

---

> CAR (vehicle) + NATION (synonym for country)

Comment: Both answers are correct